# How to send direct message to ipfs peer with http api

Tags: ipfs

I want to use `ipfs` + http api for chat-like communication. Simple scenario:

1) Client subscribes to `pubsub` topic with `/api/v0/pubsub/sub`
2) Client gets peers for topic with `/api/v0/pubsub/peers`
**3)** Client send direct message to peer

But I didn't find api for 3 punkt. How to send direct message to peer in `pubsub` topic with http api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send direct messages to peers with the ipfs http api. You can however publish a message to the pubsub topic both peers are subscribed to using the `pubsub/pub` api call https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/http/#api-v0-pubsub-pub